# drf-yasg: how to skip some operations during generate_swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I use Django with [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html). I have a REST endpoint similar to the following:

```py
@swagger_auto_schema(
    method="POST",
    request_body=...
)
@api_view(["POST"])
def do_something(request: Request) -> HttpResponse:
    ...
```

When I run the server, I see the `do_something` operation in `/swagger` panel, which is fine.

Now, when I run `./manage.py generate_swagger` I would like `do_something` operation to NOT show in the resulting OpenAPI yaml. I would like to be able to somehow annotate the operation to be conditionally included, like with some custom `@include_conditionally` decorator:

```py
@include_conditionally
@swagger_auto_schema(...)
@api_view(["POST"])
def do_something(request: Request) -> HttpResponse:
    ...
```

I know that setting `auto_schema=None` [prevents the endpoint](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#excluding-endpoints) from being included in Swagger, but it excludes the endpoint from both Swagger web panel and the yaml schema, which I do not want.

I tried to use my own generator in `./manage.py generate_swagger -g MyGenerator`

```py
class MyGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
    def should_include_endpoint(self, path, method, view, public):
        ...
```

while `should_include_endpoint` seems to be the right way to go, I failed to detect if the operation was annotated with `include_conditionally`.

Background: I want to exclude some of the endpoints from being exposed with [Google ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-proxy-startup-options) while being available locally.

How can I exclude some endpoints conditionally from being included in Swagger schema yaml file?